# Django ModelChoiceField allow objects creation

Tags: python, django, forms

Django's [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) is the default form field used for foreign keys when deriving a form from a model using [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). Upon validation, the field will check that selected value does exist in the corresponding related table, and raise a `ValidationError` if it is not the case.

I'm creating a form for a `Document` model that has a `type` field, a foreign key to a `Type` model which does only contain a `name` attribute. Here is the code of `models.py` for clarity

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, related_name='related_documents')
```

Instead of a standard `select` control, I'm using [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) to provide auto-completion to the users. Moreover, selectize provides a "create" option, that allows to enter a value that does not exist yet into the select.

I would like to extend the `ModelChoiceField` in order to create a new `Type` object when the selected value does not exist (the new value will be assigned to `name` field, this should be an option of the field for reusability). If possible, I would like the object to not be inserted into DB until `save()` is called on the validated form (to prevent that multiple failed validation create multiple rows in db). What would be a good way to do so in Django? I tried to look into the documentation and the source code, tried to override `ModelChoiceField` and tried to build this behavior basted on a `TextField` but I'm not sure if there isn't a simpler way to do it.

I looked into the following questions but couldn't find the answer.

- [Django ModelChoiceField has no plus button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738172/how-to-set-initial-value-in-a-dynamic-django-modelchoicefield)
- [Django: override RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156028/django-override-relatedfieldwidgetwrapper)
- [How to set initial value in a dynamic Django ModelChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738172/how-to-set-initial-value-in-a-dynamic-django-modelchoicefield)

I would like to keep the process of adding new types as simple as possible - i.e.: do not use a pop-up attached to a '+' button. User should be able to type the value, and the value gets created if it doesn't exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it'd be easier without using a ModelForm. You could create a list of all of your `Type` objects then pass that to the template as a context variable. Then, you could use that list to construct a `<select>` element. Then use jquery and `selectize` to add the necessary attributes to the form.

```
#views.py
...
types = Type.objects.all()
...



#template.html
...
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type='text' name='title'>
    <select name='type' id='id_type'>
        {% for type in types %}
            <option value="{{type.id}}">{{type.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#id_type').selectize({
    create: true
    });
</script>
...
```

Then when you get a form submission, you can process it in a simple view function:

```
if request.method == POST:
        title_post = request.POST.get('title','')
        type_post = request.POST.get('type',None)
        if type_post is not None:
            try:
                #If an existing Type was selected, we'll have an ID to lookup
                type = Type.objects.get(id=type_post)
            except:
                #If that lookup failed, we've got a user-inputted name to use
                type = Type.objects.create(name=type_post)
            new_doc = Document.objects.create(title=title_post, type=type)
```

Comment: That'd probably work, but I was hoping I could keep all the nice features `ModelForm` provides such as calling `form.save()` (the actual `Document` have more fields than those listed in the question). Moreover encapsulating all of this into its own form field would be nice :)