# ModelMultipleChoiceField django and debug mode

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i'm trying to implement a ModelMultipleChoiceField in my application, like that: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809057/django-form-select-multipe-allow-to-add-the-objects)

model.py

```
class Services(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Professionals_Services(models.Model):
    professional = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Services, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

form.py

```
class ProfileServicesUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Services.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Professionals_Services
        fields = ['service']

    def clean(self):
        # this condition only if the POST data is cleaned, right?
        cleaned_data = super(ProfileServicesUpdateForm, self).clean()
        print(cleaned_data.get('service'))
```

view.py

```
class EditProfileServicesView(CreateView):
    model = Professionals_Services
    form_class = ProfileServicesUpdateForm
    context_object_name = 'services'
    template_name = 'accounts/edit-profile.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('professionals:login')))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            services = form.save(commit=False)
            services.save()
```

html

```
<select class="ui search fluid dropdown" multiple="" name="service" id="id_service">
  {% for service in services_list %}
    <option value="{{ service.id }}">{{ service.type }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

For development i'm using Pycham Professionals(latest version) with docker, when i run the application and i try to make a POST the answer is:

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Services: Services object (2)>, <Services: Services object (5)>, <Services: Services object (6)>, <Services: Services object (7)>]>": "Professionals_Services.service" must be a "Services" instance.
```

But if i run the application in debug mode and with a breakpoints on the `if form.is_valid():`
the application works fine

That's because the validate is equal to Unknown not in debug

you know how to fix?

Comment: `service` is a `ForeignKey`, so that means you can only select a *single* item. For multiple ones, you should use a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `service` is a `ForeignKey`:

```
    service = models.ForeignKey(Services, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A `ForeignKey` means that you select a *single* element, not multiple ones. You use a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to select multiple elements:

```
class Professionals_Services(models.Model):
    professional = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
```

You should also not override the `post` method, and you can make use of the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) to ensure that the user is logged in:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class EditProfileServicesView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('professionals:login')
    model = Professionals_Services
    form_class = ProfileServicesUpdateForm
    context_object_name = 'services'
    template_name = 'accounts/edit-profile.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In your `Form` you should also return the cleaned data:

```
class ProfileServicesUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Services.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Professionals_Services
        fields = ['service']

    def clean(self):
        # this condition only if the POST data is cleaned, right?
        cleaned_data = super(ProfileServicesUpdateForm, self).clean()
        print(cleaned_data.get('service'))
        return cleaned_data
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Professionals_Services`</s> to `ProfessionalService`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Services` instead of <s>`Service`</s>.